# How to get CPU utilization using Javascript or Java

Tags: java, javascript

How can I get the CPU utilization of client's machine.

I have created a Java web application and where I need to get the CPU utilization of client's machine.

Can it be done using either Javascript or Java?

Comment: Do you mean Java or Javascript?

Comment: Right now it is unclear whether or not you are asking about the `Java` or `Javascript` programming languages.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: I need to achieve the task , whether in JSP or Javascript any thing.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you use, Java or Javascript, you can't get CPU utilization of the client's machine. That will be a huge security risk. The only way to do it will be to install a plug-in. This wouldn't help too much however, as reading the CPU utilization is platform specific.

Comment: You need to create an applet. The applet would need to use JNI to measure CPU usage. This will be platform specific. Then you need to ask the users to install the applet. I don't have an easy solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

It may look like a security risk, but there is a technique to get an estimate of the CPU usage with JavaScript inside the browser. You may want to check this article:

- [Ajaxian - JPU: JavaScript CPU Monitor](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jpu-javascript-cpu-monitor) ([Demo here](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2007/09/jpu-javascript-cpu-monitor.html))

As [kgiannakakis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24054/kgiannakakis) noted in a comment below, this calculation is based on the delay of `setInterval()` calls.

I remember seeing a similar implementation on [Mindmeister.com](http://www.mindmeister.com) (showing the CPU usage while editing a mind map.)

Comment: This provides an estimation of CPU usage, based on the delay of setInterval calls.

Comment: The first link seems to no longer work. Is this method still working in modern browsers? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel provides a link to a method that (on a good day) would give an approximate measure of CPU usage.

@kgiannakakis says that this would be a serious security risk.

But I wonder.  How could an attacker exploit CPU usage levels to compromise the user machine's security, or steal sensitive information about the user?  Off the top of my head, I cannot think of anything realistic.

The only possible risk I can think of would be if the attacker had already installed/launched some spy software somewhere else on the user's machine.  The ability to measure CPU usage could be used to implement a "[covert channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covert_channel)" to get information from the spy s/w to the outside world.  But this is only of theoretical interest (unless you are trying to implement A1 / A2 level security).

Answer (score 0):

If its java look at OperatingSystemMXBean using the please be aware this is Java 1.6 only.

```
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemInfo = 
    (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
```

I am not sure how well this works in an applet.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple example of a CPU usage monitor demonstrates how to use XML DOM capabilities of client JavaScript in a BSP application to dynamically request data from server and adjust corresponding elements of the screen without reloading the whole page.

This [article](https://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/library/standards-and-open-source/A%20Simple%20CPU%20Monitor%20Using%20JavaScript.article) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

jni concept for cpu utilization

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-11/01-qa-1108-cpu.html?page=1

try this link

Answer (score 0):

I once looked into creating a Web Start application that could be launched by a user to "scan" their system hardware. Luckily, the targeted systems were Windows boxes, so I used the Jacob package (Google or search this site for info) to do a WMI query for things like serial numbers, etc.

I created a proof of concept Swing client app, but never got around to the Web Start portion.